# variance of error term(econometrics)

Tags: econometrics, variance

[image]

I don't understand that the pointed part(with a red circle) is a negative sign. I expect it should be a positive sign since the whole parenthesis was squared. I don't know where I got wrong.

Comment: Pure econometrics questions without connection to economics should be posted on cross validated stack exchange.

Comment: It is a direct consequence of the three first lines (and orthogonality).

Comment: @1muflon1: Actually, according to [our policies](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), econometrics questions, including the theoretical ones, are on topic.

Comment: @HerrK. Oh I seen in past pure econometric questions being directed towards cross validated but I will retract my close vote then thanks for letting me know